# Dynamically set assumed role in lambda based on invokation

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-iam

How would you implement a security model with the following situation:

- Users are able to "write" their own lambda functions and share them with other users.
- This lambda should only be allowed to assume a role dynamically on a per-user basis. For example based on a "userId" key that's delivered via the event object (Reason being: the lambda function writes sensitive files to a "userId" specific path in a s3 bucket)
- the same lambda code should be executable by other users with their respective execution policies without just copy pasting the lambda code and just having a different execution policy.

Is there a way to give permissions to a lambda function dynamically at runtime? For example assuming a role that is based on the user executing it?

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible using policy variables.

For example, if your "users" are IAM users and the prefix of your S3 buckets includes the username then you could use

```
"Condition": {"StringLike": {"s3:prefix": ["${aws:username}/*"]}}
```

in an IAM policy for accessing S3 and attach it to each IAM user.

See the [documentation on policy variables](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_variables.html).